# Multiple buttons, one event to change clicked button colour

Tags: vb.net, button

The code shown below should allow any button on the page to change colour except for the ones named in the first `if` statement. This code was working but now does nothing when the button is clicked. The button should turn yellow but just stays the default colour. Also is there anyway I can manipulate the code so only one button can be red at a time instead of allowing multiple red buttons. When reading into this. I cannot find any help for vb. Can anyone help?

Personally, I think it may be to do with the`Public Sub` since the message box does not appear when a field is empty.

```
Public Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Click
    Try
        Dim btn As Button = sender
        If btn.Name = "BtnUpdate" Or btn.Name = "BtnBackCust" Or btn.Name = "BtnConfirm" Then
        ElseIf TxtFirstName.Text = "" Or TxtLastName.Text = "" Or TxtAddress.Text = "" Or cboCountry.SelectedItem = "" Or cboRoomType.SelectedItem = "" Then
            MsgBox("You must populate all fields")
        Else
            btn.BackColor = Color.Red
            btn.Text = ChosenRoom
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe if you let the code throw the exception instead of hiding it you could find your problem. Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see what is happening when it is clicked? Are you sure it's even going in the event?

Comment: For your other question, you could keep the Name of the button that is currently red in a variable somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `MyBase.Click` Event, create an Handle for each Button on your Form Load:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each Button As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
        If Button.Name <> "BtnUpdate" AndAlso Button.Name <> "BtnBackCust" AndAlso Button.Name <> "BtnConfirm" Then
            AddHandler Button.Click, AddressOf ChangeColor
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The `ChangeColor` sub, also create the `RedButton` variable to keep track of what is the currently red button:

```
Private RedButton As Button = Nothing
Private Sub ChangeColor(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If TypeOf Sender Is Button Then
        If TxtFirstName.Text = "" OrElse TxtLastName.Text = "" OrElse TxtAddress.Text = "" OrElse cboCountry.SelectedItem = "" OrElse cboRoomType.SelectedItem = "" Then
            MsgBox("You must populate all fields")
        Else
            Dim SenderButton As Button = Sender
            If RedButton IsNot Nothing Then
                RedButton.BackColor = Me.BackColor
            End If
            If SenderButton IsNot RedButton Then 'This if will toogle the button between Red and the Normal color
                SenderButton.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If

            RedButton = Sender
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```