# VB.net how to: multiple buttons call the same form but change different Settings entry?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I'd like to make my own soundboard to improve my coding skills. I started a Windows Forms Application project and started building:
1 form will have 12 buttons and an eventlogger and a second one will have adjustable parameters for those buttons (path & name).

I'd like to push a button and open the 2nd form to change the settings for the button pushed. I can get this to work for button 1 but is there a way to avoid repeating the same code 12x for each button pressed?

I'm now trying to implement the code provided in this sub: [Multiple buttons, one event to change clicked button colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205800/multiple-buttons-one-event-to-change-clicked-button-colour)

All help is appreciated so I can better understand coding :)

Following is some code from the 1st form:

```
Public Class SoundBoardUI

Private WithEvents My_SettingsForm As SettingsForm
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each Button As Button In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
        AddHandler Button.Click, AddressOf ChangeNr
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeNr(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If TypeOf Sender Is Button Then
        Dim SenderButton As Button = Sender
        'Make code here so I know what button is pressed in the second form.
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1Settings_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1Settings.Click
    Dim settingsForm As New SettingsForm
    AddHandler settingsForm.FormClosed, AddressOf settingForm_Formclosed
    settingsForm.Show()
End Sub
```

This is some code from the 2nd form:

```
Public Class SettingsForm

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk

    PathtBox.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName 'Path of selected file  

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BrowsePath.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\" 'Set the directory name  
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Open an audio file" 'Set the title name of the OpenDialog Box  
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Audio|*.mp3" 'Set the filter to display only mp3.
    OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "*.mp3" 'Set the default filename

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    My.Settings.Btn1Path = PathtBox.Text 'I'd like to automaticly chane the My.settings entry to the button pressed here.
    My.Settings.Btn1Name = NametBox.Text
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can use the `Tag` Property to set the identifier of your Buttons (e.g., Button1 - or whatever it's named - has `Tag = "1"`). Then you can use the Tag when you get the related settings (e.g., `dim btn = DirectCast(sender, Button`). Show your Dialog then inspect the new values (add `public` properties to `SettingsForm` that reference these values). Update the settings on exit: e.g., `My.MySettings.Default($"Btn{btn.Tag}Path") = settingsForm.NewPath` etc. (assuming the Public Property that references the `PathtBox.Text` content has been named `NewPath`)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jimi
Is the reason you use a Dollar sign in _Default($"Btn(btn.Tag)Path")_ because it should treat the string as code?

Comment: That's an [Interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/strings/interpolated-strings). The value of the `btn.Tab` property is the interpolated expression, which is added to the rest of the string (i.e., it's `String.Format()` in a more concise form)